# What is my current scope if I change `Inspector>Cell options>Evaluation options>CellContext` to "Notebook"?

Tags: contexts, system

I mean I made this change:

[image]

Now,

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

and

```
Names["Global`*"]
```

are not working anymore. I tried different combinations with `Notebook` but they does not work. How can I address scope in my case?

Comment: What do you get when you evaluate `Context[]` after making this change?

Comment: @JasonB. Global scope becomes limited to notebook and not across all notebooks (as is with default setting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `CellContext -> Notebook` gives each notebook its own context. Details can be found in [`CellContext`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellContext.html) documentation.

You may view the current context with [`$Context`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Context.html).

```
$Context
```

> ```
> Notebook$$32$541062`
> ```

You still declare variables as normal and they are placed in the current `$Context`.

```
x = 5;
Context[x]
```

> ```
> Notebook$$32$541062`
> ```

All of the variables in the current context can be listed with [`Names`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Names.html) using the current context shorthand or by explicitly naming the context.

```
Names[$Context <> "*"]
Names["`*"]
```

Both give

> ```
> {"x"}
> ```

[`Information`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html) and [`Definition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Definition.html) can be used without specifying the context because name resolution occurs in the inner most scope/context and works it way outwards.

```
?x
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

You still have access to the `` Global` ``  context. Which can be useful to pass state from one notebook to the other if needed.  You must specify the context to access variables outside of the current context.

```
Global`x = 10;
x
Global`x
```

> ```
> 5
> 10
> ```

```
Names["`*"]
Names["Global`*"]
```

> ```
> {"x"}
> {"Global`x"}
> ```

You can [`Clear`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear.html) and [`Remove`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Remove.html) variables without specifying the context because name resolution occurs in the inner most scope/context and works it way outwards.

```
Remove[x]
Names["`*"]
Names["Global`*"]
```

> ```
> {}
> {"Global`x"}
> ```

You do have to specify the context to clear variables outside of the current context.

```
Remove[Global`x]
Names["Global`*"]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

I always use the Notebook setting as I tend to have a couple of different analysis going at the same time and this prevents naming conflicts between notebooks.

Read more in the [Context section](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html#27982)  of the [Modularity and the Naming of Things](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html) tech note.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for great explanation!

Comment: This works for clearing all variables: ```Clear["Notebook$$34$511107`*"]```

Comment: @vasili111 You only need ``Clear["`*"]  ``.

Comment: Great! Thank you!