# Construct string argument and pass it to command

Tags: evaluation, string-manipulation

My Mathematica variable scope is set to `Notebook`, more about it here: [What is my current scope if I change `Inspector>Cell options>Evaluation options>CellContext` to "Notebook"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225752/what-is-my-current-scope-if-i-change-inspectorcell-optionsevaluation-options)

Now I want to clear all variables from the scope.

I am getting current scope:

```
In[61]:= $Context
Out[61]= Notebook$$34$511107`
```

After I am using this output by manually constructing this command and it works (clear all variables from the scope):

```
Clear["Notebook$$34$511107`*"]
```

All above works well.
Now I want to do that programatically. I tried this:

```
Clear[Evaluate["\"" <> $Context <> "*\""]]
```

also this:

```
Clear["\"" <> Evaluate[$Context] <> "*\""]
```

but without any success.

How to fix code above to make it work?

Comment: I found universal option to use `Clean[]` for all cases: ```Clear["`*"]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn `$Context` into a string. You also do not need to add the quotation marks, as you are joining strings, so the end result will automatically be a string again.

This should do what you want.

```
Clear@Evaluate[ToString[$Context] <> "*"]
```